# Swift parsing XML

Tags: swift, xml-parsing

I want to parse this XML file: http://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/37178.xml .

It's hierarchical and I'm stuck trying to get data from `<temperature>` for different elements (for example, `<yesterday>` and `<fact>` have the same element inside named `<temperature>`).

Also, I would be very happy if you tell me where I can read about parsing cycle, because that's a root of my problem. Here's my not working code. `yesterdayTemp` variable isn't changing.

```
class EntryPageViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate, TableViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var yesterdayTempLabel: UILabel!

var yesterdayTemp: String = String()
var parser: NSXMLParser!
var element: String?
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/37178.xml")!
var object = Dictionary<String, String>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}

var parseYesterday = false

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    element = elementName
    if (element == "yesterday"){
        //object.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        parseYesterday = true
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
    var data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    if !parseYesterday{
        return
    }
    if let temp = object[element!]{
        var tempString = temp
        tempString += string
        object[element!] = tempString
    }
    else{
        object[element!] = string
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
    if (element == "yesterday"){
        parseYesterday = false
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    yesterdayTempLabel.text = object["temperature"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Did you write any code yet? Wont you share it with us, so we can help you better?

Comment: I've added my code. I believe that solution is quite different. I don't understand how this parser works, that's a problem.